# Before and After Dates for a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to have Column B Be the date that I enter (as a start date) then Column C would be 6 months after column B, then coulmn D would be 30 days before column to C.
Can you help me and also where do I enter so the whole column follows these rules

Comment: What exactly is 6 months? Aug 31 -> Feb 31 = 6 months won't work so it's 6x30 days?

Comment: tHIS ISNOT HELPING ME

Comment: wHERE DO i ENTER THE FORMULA

Comment: you enter the formula directly into the cell. if the date is in cell `B1` you put the first formula `=B1+180` into cell `C1` etc.

Comment: @MichelleCramer,, better use `DATE` function & `+6` to `Month` for `C1` and `-30` to `Day` for `D1`.

Comment: Is this a homework question or assignment, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you use 180 days as 6 months you can use the following formulas

```
   B            C           D
1  01.12.2019   =B1+180     =C1-30
```

which will result in:

```
   B            C            D
1  01.12.2019   29.05.2020   29.04.2020
```